# Align two divs in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following output:
[image]

The blue circle is in one `div` and the text is in another.  I can't understand why the first div is on top and the second seems not to be aligned with each other.

Below here the code:

css

```
#circles {
    background: #4A90E2;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
     display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
     color: white;
     font-size: 23px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="row" style="background-color: rgba(140,  140,  140, 0.33);"> 

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-5">
                     <div class="row" style="padding-top: 20px;">
                         <div class="col-sm-1">
                            <div id="circles"> 
                                1 
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-sm-11 pull-right">
                            <h2 style="vertical-align:top;">Maak je pakje klaar</h2>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

I tried with vertical-align but without results.

Comment: can you provide bootply or jsfiddle ? an working example ..

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap have some default css value on elements for example heading tag have

```
h1, .h1, h2, .h2, h3, .h3 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

You need to remove it or manage it according your need.

Here you can use:

```
h2 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

But better option is you should [customize Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) before use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `Fiddle` Hope this will help you.  - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e93m7uk1/1/)

Also please read about bootstraps class.